# What happens when calling reactiveMongoTemplate query in a switchIfEmpty, if the upstream was received with value?

Tags: rx-java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-mongo-java

In my application I have a switchIfEmpty pipeline that I'm having hard time to understand how it's working (or more specifically, how it's handing cancellation)

The purpose of the pipeline is to create a customer, and it's getting a customer object.

The first part of the pipeline is calling a reactiveMongoTemplate, searching for a customer document in my Database, based on the received customer id.
Then, if it's not being found (i.e -  received Mono.empty from the upstream), the switchIfEmpty calls a function that creates the customer.

I know that switchIfEmpty eagerly subscribes, and I'm not using solutions like Mono.defer in the pipeline, and yet, the customer isn't being created if the upstream find it.

```
Customer customer = new Customer("details of customer to be searched by");
findCustomer(customer) //calls a reactiveMongoTemplate find() function
.switchIfEmpty(saveCustomer(customer)); //calls a reactiveMongoTemplate save() function
```

This is the wanted behavior of course, but I just don't understand what happens in the background

Is a cancel() function being called? is the request being disposed of? how does mongo/reactiveMongoTemplate know what to revert?

Thanks for the answers!!!